Cannot import javax.swing in Eclipse
Here's the code. It said the package javax.swing is not accessible and jOptionPane cannot be resolved.
import javax.swing.jOptionPane;
public class GUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = jOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
    }

}

I've googled up solutions and every video told me to add library. However it said here that all of my options in execution environment are unbound:
(https://i.sstatic.net/AQETwa8J.png).
When I click on alternate JRE I don't see anything:
(https://i.sstatic.net/GLRtgCQE.png).
I've also installed JDK but when I try to add it on alternate JRE it said no JRE found: JDK same thing happens with jdk-21. I'm currently using the workspace default JRE and it works just fine but then I encounter this problem. Does anyone has a solution to this? I'm new to programming and stuff so thanks very much if you can solve my problem.

this is likely because you have import javax.swing.jOptionPane instead of javax.swing.JOptionPane; I very much doubt it works in oanother JRE

I've changed it to JOptionPane but it's still the same problem.

you've also used it like that in your code.

you mean to change it to import javax.swing.JOptionPane right? I've tried that in Eclispe but I still can't import it.

You probably have a module-info.java file so are using the Java 9+ module system which requires you to say you want to use this module. Just delete the module-info.java file to stop using the module system.

For Java 21, set the Execution environment: to JavaSE-21 and make sure that in preferences Java > Installed JREs you have configured a Java 21 JDK (for Java 22 you have to wait for the next release or install the Java 22 support from the Marketplace). If you have a module-info.java file, delete it.

I deleted the module file and it works now. Thanks a lot guys!

Don't delete module-info.java (this is not recommended) but add the requires java.desktop; in it.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Whether the module-info.java file is recommended or not depends on one's needs (e.g. think of the limitations of JPMS compared to OSGi). Note that the module-info.java file can be (re-)create at any time via right-clicking on the project folder and choosing Configure > Create module-info.java.
